# Aggregating the date fields in R

Tags: r, aggregate

in the following data frame

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
date<-c(NA,NA,"22-11-07",NA,NA,NA,NA,"23-11-07",NA)

df<-data.frame(id,date)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")


id     date      date2
1     <NA>       <NA>
1     <NA>       <NA>
1 23-11-07 2007-11-22
1     <NA>       <NA>
1     <NA>       <NA>
3     <NA>       <NA>
3     <NA>       <NA>
3 23-11-07 2007-11-23
3     <NA>       <NA>
```

is there any way to make an aggregation based on `date` and `id` and get the following data frame?

```
id    date2
1    2007-11-22
3    2007-11-23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the `aggregate` approach, if that's what you're looking for:

```
aggregate(date2 ~ id + date, df, c)
  id     date      date2
1  1 22-11-07 2007-11-22
2  3 23-11-07 2007-11-23
```

You can use `aggregate(date2 ~ id + date, df, c)[, -2]` to drop the `date` column *after* aggregation, since according to your problem, you're aggregating on both `id` and `date`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
na.omit(df)[,-2]
```

`na.omit` deletes the NAs and `[,-2]` deletes the second column.

Comment: This gets the required output, but it's not really aggregation, is it?

Comment: Yes, but aggregating a value with NAs is the same than juste taking the value, isn't it ? I didn't really see the point... but you're right.